X's largest price changes in the last Y bars
I want the script to plot 1 in the bar chart when the price change is one of X's largest in the last Y bars.
I find the absolute price change. Tried copying array fragment from Gemini, but it doesn't work. I think array does not persist from bar to bar and is created again and again.
Please put me on track how to achieve this goal.
//@version=5

// Define the lookback period
lookback = 52

// Calculate the percentage change for each candle
percentageChange = (close - close[1]) / close[1] * 100

absolutePercentageChange = math.abs(percentageChange)

isLargestChange = 0

// Create an array to store the 10 largest price changes
largestChanges = array.new_float(10)

for i = 0 to lookback - 1
    if array.size(largestChanges) > 0 and absolutePercentageChange[i] > array.get(largestChanges, 9)
        // Replace the smallest value in the array with the new price change
        array.set(largestChanges, 9, absolutePercentageChange[i])
        array.sort(largestChanges, order.descending)
        isLargestChange := 1
    else if array.size(largestChanges) < 10
        // Add the price change to the array
        array.push(largestChanges, absolutePercentageChange[i])
        array.sort(largestChanges, order.descending)

        
// Plot largest changes
plot(isLargestChange, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth = 4)

